# ¿Cómo redireccionar estas URLs?

Tags: php, html

Necesito modificar una página. Si la abro desde el ***localhost***, con *WampServer*, se muestra el inicio pero ***los links del menú no funcionan***.

Algunos de los enlaces:

```
<div class="nav_top">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="sub_bt" id="top1">
                <span class="sub-open"><?php echo r('app', 'Gobierno Corporativo ') ?></span>
                <div class="con-sub clearfix">
                    <div class="con-sub-body">
                        <?php foreach ($gobierno as $value): ?>
                            <a href='<?php echo $this->createUrl('/'.$value->slug); ?>'><?php echo $value->categoria; ?></a>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <a href='<?php echo $this->createUrl('/'.r('app', 'cumplimiento')) ?>'><?php echo r('app', 'Cumplimiento') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/'.r('app','noticias')) ?>" id="top2"><?php echo r('app','Noticias') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/'.r('app', 'trabaje')) ?>" id="top3"><?php echo r('app', 'Trabaje Con Nosotros') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $intranet->link ?>" id="top4" target="_blank"><?php echo r('app', 'Intranet') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/'.r('app', 'contactenos')) ?>" id="top5"><?php echo r('app', 'Contactenos') ?></a></li>
        <li><a class="register-bt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mb_register"><?php echo r('app', 'Suscribete') ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: esto por qué está etiquetado como `sql`?

Comment: probablemente los links son absolutos y no relativos

Comment: ok mira modifique uno de los links de esta manera

Comment: ok mira modifique uno de los links de esta manera                                                                          <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/app/modules/noticias/views/page/index'.r('app', ''))?>" id="top2"><?php echo r('app', 'Noticias') ?></a></li>                         
 pero en el index me sale el siguente error                                                   ( ! ) Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp64\www\Tuscanydrilling\app\modules\noticias\views\page\index.php on line 4

Comment: se supone que que es por esto                                                                       $this->breadcrumbs=array(
 $this->module->id,
);
?>